# How to remove error: the replacement path doesn't exist in XCode

Tags: xcode

I deleted an old project from my Mac, and now in my current project, which has no connections with the old I get a message:

```
error: the replacement path doesn't exist: "/path/to/old/project"
```

when I run on my ios device.

1. How it possible? These two projects never have any relations
2. How to fix it?

Comment: Did you delete the derived data and restart the computer?

Comment: @matt yes, it doesn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61294284/where-are-the-llvm-environment-variables-or-how-is-the-llvm-environment-configur

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I made some investigation.

### First solution

First and lazy solution - you can **turn off** the **"debug executable"** option **in your scheme**:

[screenshot of the first solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Df8gm.png)

### Second solution

Actually, you can find some files under your `~/` directory, they are hidden, so you should use `command + shift + .` to see them:

[screenshot of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAq1D.png)

`.lldbinit` and (maybe a little different) `.lldbinit-tulsiproj`
in my case, I think, it was connected because a building of Telegram.app and little touch a Bazel thing https://bazel.build/

... so, just delete them both and you are happy with a clear debug console!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what I faced with too. When participate in Telegram iOS dev contest, was working with Telegram sources, and thats messages start droping in to my Xcode console. Deleting `.lldbinit-Xcode` and `.lldbinit-rules_xcodeproj` in my case helps.[image]